# How do I keep my windows10 computer screen from going to sleep after 30 seconds

Tags: windows-10

I have a Lenovo Ideacentre all in one desktop and I have changed all the appropriate settings but no matter what I put for settings after 30 seconds not interacting with the screen it goes to my screen saver the 10 senconds after that it goes to sleep. I read somewhere that I have to change something in my registry but I can’t find where I read it and I don’t know what I’m supposed to change. Could someone please help me? It is getting so annoying not to be able to read anything on my computer unless I constantly wiggle my mouse. Please help.

Comment: Windows 10 is a little weird because it has both the "Settings" app and the "control panel" app.

Some things, for example setting your default browser, if you set it in "control panel", will be overridden by whatever is set in "settings". I.e no matter how many times you set Chrome as default in control panel, if you don't set it in settings, Edge will still be default. 

Try make sure you have the relevant power settings set in both "Settings" and "Control Panel"

Comment: I do have both settings and control panel set correctly and they have not changed although I’ve changed them to every configuration possible and no results.

Comment: Have you tried turning off hibernation and sleep modes?

Comment: I have tried everything.

Comment: Months ago I read it is some registry setting but I can’t find where I read that from and I don’t know anything about registry settings but I’ve made sure that all other setting are correct and I’ve gone into permissions to see if it was something in there. I’ve changed settings as a regular user as well as an administrator and it still goes to sleep after 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try saving the following as a .bat file and running it as admin or using the commands in an elevated cmd.

```
POWERCFG -Change -monitor-timeout-ac 5
POWERCFG -Change -monitor-timeout-dc 5
POWERCFG -Change -disk-timeout-ac 5
POWERCFG -Change -disk-timeout-dc 5
POWERCFG -Change -standby-timeout-ac 5
POWERCFG -Change -standby-timeout-dc 5
POWERCFG -H OFF
```

This will set timeout for everything to be 5 mins and disable Hibernate mode if it's enabled. You can then play with the timeouts as desired.

Comment: If I’m understanding you correctly I should go into my command prompt as an administrator and type what you have into the prompt. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, right click on command prompt and select run as administrator. 

Each line I have typed is a separate command that needs to be run.

Comment: Thank you. I will do that. Can I ask one other question? Where does the .bat file fall into place and what is a .bat file

Comment: A .bat file is a windows batch file. It is a file containing a sequence of commands that will be run sequentially when the .bat file is run.

Where it could have come into play here is if you didn't want to bother typing each individual command into cmd. You could have opened notepad, copy-pasted the block of code into the editor, and saved this file with the .bat extension which would let windows know the file contained cmd commands. 
Running this file would then execute the commands contained within.

Comment: Thank you. You explained that very well. I grately appreciate your help and I typed all your stuff one at a time which gave me more practice with the command prompt and it worked. It does not go to sleep now after 30 seconds. You have made this old lady very happy. Thank You. Thank You. Thank You.

Comment: No problem at all, if you wouldn't mind, please mark my answer as the accepted answer so future users can see this solution if they have the same problem. Glad I could be of help to you!

Comment: Yes. I will gladly do that. I hope you have a great day and thank you again.